# Generating random variates knowing the density function

Tags: distributions, self-study, random-variable, simulation, density-function

Let's consider a random variable that is following the distribution with the density function as below:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} 3.5i(0.3)^{i-1}e^{-5ix} & \text{for $x>0$} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

In previous examples, it usually was about the mixture of two distributions. Here one distribution is quite obvious, the exponential one with rate $\lambda = 5i$. I am having a hard time identifying the second distribution. To some extent, it seems like it is a geometric distribution but the term $3.5$ seems a bit off (to my contention, it should be $0.7$?). Iit also seems weird to me is that the rate of exponential distribution here depends on $i$? I guess in the generation process it would not matter that much?

The answer states:

1. set $i=1$
2. generate uniform random variable $U_1 \sim U(0,1)$
3. if $U_1 < 0.3$ then set $i = i+1$ and go to step 2.
4. generate uniform random variable $U_2 \sim U(0,1)$ and output $X = -\frac{\ln(U_2)}{5i}$

Knowing the pdf, it is clear why we use the acceptance-rejection method **BUT** I find step 3. a bit unclear. Any hint or idea would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a geometric mixture of exponentials.  After you integrate the density function that will become clear: the value of that strange constant is $3.5 =  0.7\times 5.$

Comment: Maybe the complicated look of the pdf is why it's being used as an example for the acceptance-rejection method but it simplifies to $\frac{350 e^{5 x}}{\left(10 e^{5 x}-3\right)^2}$.  So setting $x=\frac{1}{5} \log \left(\frac{3 u-10}{10 (u-1)}\right)$ will get you a random sample from that distribution where $u$ is a random sample from a $U(0,1)$.